# sublime eventlistener on close tab not triggered

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext

I have a plugin that listenes for events regarding closing tabs:

```
def on_window_command(self, window, cmd, args):
    if cmd == 'close':
    ...
```

When closing a tab with `ctrl+w`, the event is captured correctly. But when closing the tab by clicking the `x` in the tab the event is not captured at all, meaning that the method `on_window_command` is not even triggered.

Is there a way that event can be caught as well?

EDIT:
I can't use `on_close` or `on_pre_close` since those seem to be called after sublime checks the content for occurred changes and then would pop the popup for saving the content before closing. But I want to do something before that which was possible with the `on_window_command`

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to capture a tab close event is using an [`EventListener`'s `on_close` or `on_pre_close`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) callback:

> `on_pre_close(view)`
>
> Called when a view is about to be closed. The view will still be in the window at this point.
>
> `on_close(view)`
>
> Called when a view is closed (note, there may still be other views into the same buffer).

Currently, there is no way to receive a "closing" event that would occur before you are prompted to save the file, see https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/821